# HTML editor "Cannot resolve directory"

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

PHPStorm/WebStorm raises warnings in HTML files for links to local resources.

My project structure is:

```
hello-world
|--assets
|  |--css
|  |--images
|  |--js
|  +--lib
|     +--foo
|        |--foo.js
|        +--foo.css
|--src
|--templates
|  |--foo.html
|  +--bar.html
|--test
|--packages
+--index.php
```

Given I render foo.html to the user, Apache can only locate local resources when they are referenced relative to Apache's root, ie:

```
src="/hello-world/assets/lib/foo/foo.js"
href="/hello-world/assets/lib/foo/foo.css"
```

but PHPStorm/WebStorm will only resolve these files as:

```
src="/assets/lib/foo/foo.js"
href="/assets/lib/foo/foo.css"
```

which, of course, causes 404 errors when Apache tries to serve them and can't find them.

I have tried changing the directory settings, making my project root a resource root, my assets folder a resource root, lib folder, etc. Nothing makes the IDE happy and as it stands all of my HTML and JavaScript code is full of false errors and unresolved references.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by modifying Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory /var/www/hello-world>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /assets /var/www/hello-world/assets
</VirtualHost>
```

now I can just reference files as `"/assets/lib/foo/foo.js"`. Far from ideal, but Apache can find them and PHPStorm/WebStorm is happy.

Comment: *"Far from ideal, but Apache can find them ..."* yes. That's why you should learn and configure Apache to **use virtual hosts** (separate domain/url per each site) -- this way it will be more like real website on real server somewhere on internet.